# loading picture for django templates via css

Tags: python, django

I have such folder structure in my django site theme:

[image]

---

index file load the style.css and the style.css should load my bg.jpg,I do this in style.css:

```
body  {
    background:#fff url('../images/images/bg.jpg') repeat-x;
}
```

but it doesn't work,I,ve tryed this,too:

```
body  {
        background:#fff url('sitestatic/images/images/bg.jpg') repeat-x;
    }
```

css URL : /sitestatic/css/style.css

image URL : /sitestatic/images/images/bg.jpg

how can I load this picture via style.css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read the documentation about [how to manage static files with django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

Comment: I used the same URL in a HTML document and it works well,but in css it doesn't work!!

Comment: Could you edit your question, and add the full url of your css and your image?

Answer (score 1):

Try: background:#fff url(../images/images/bg.jpg) repeat-x;

The URL should be without the single quotes. BTW why do you have two "images" directories nested?

Comment: Are you sure that you can open the image with absolute URL?

Comment: sitestatic folder is my static folder that is defined in my settings.py file.